# The derivative of $\rho e^{it}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is

$${df \over dz} \rho e^{it} = i \rho e^{it} \text{?}$$

The **product rule** states that

$$
{df\over dz}(f_1 \cdot f_2) = f_1 f'_2 + f'_1 \cdot f_2
$$

so why doesn't this imply that

$$
{df\over dz}(\rho \cdot e^{it}) = \rho e^{it} + 0 \cdot e^{it} \text{?} = \rho e^{it} \ne i \rho e^{it} \text{?}
$$

Comment: You shouldn't write $\dfrac{df}{dz}$ when you mean $\dfrac{d}{dz}$.  Those are two different things.

Comment: @silliness. Although well intended, the notation is kind of poor. You are derving with respect to $z$ but in your formula there is no $z$ but only $i$ and $t$. Of course, these variables are linked to $z$ and so the Chain rule should be considered. Derive $it$ with respect ot $t$ and you get your answer.

Comment: Notation aside, you almost have it right--but you took the derivative of $e^{it}$ wrong; remember, for any constant $a$ we have $(e^{at})'=ae^{at}$, so $(e^{it})'=ie^{it}$.

Comment: And I should say to everyone else -- give the poor guy a break! Students often have a hard time understanding the $\frac{d}{dx}$ notation--and with good reason. It is completely obscure, and is almost always either unexplained or misexplained by teachers (yes, I mean professors). I have heard a thousand students ask, "How do I take dy over dx of this function?". The only real mistake was a simple botched derivative of an exponential expression. It was essentially correct, otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing three different things with each other:
$$
\frac{df}{dz}, \qquad \frac{d}{dz}, \qquad\frac{d}{dt}
$$

If you had written
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \rho e^{it} = \rho ie^{it}
$$
then it would be correct, but what you have written is at best a misunderstanding of notation.

Applying the product rule, one gets
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \rho e^{it} & = \rho\frac{d}{dt} e^{it} + e^{it}\frac{d\rho}{dt} \\[12pt]
& = \rho\frac{d}{dt}e^{it} + e^{it}\cdot 0 \\[12pt]
& = \rho\frac{d}{dt}e^{it}.
\end{align}
$$
Next, use the chain rule:
$$
\rho\frac{d}{dt} e^{it} = \rho e^{it} \frac{d}{dt}(it).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The product rule actually states:
$${\mathrm{d}\over \mathrm{d}z}(f_1 \cdot f_2) = f_1 \frac{\mathrm{d}f_2}{\mathrm{d}z} + \frac{\mathrm{d}f_1}{\mathrm{d}z} \cdot f_2$$

Put this together with $\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}z} \neq 0$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}}{\mathrm{d}z} \neq \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$ and the answer should be evident.